# Volume issues in Docker: Jupyter and Postgres in docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, containers, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter and Postgres via Docker Compose. However, when creating the container, the host volume mapped to the container's directory /home/jovyan/work is not available for access. I tried following some recommendations from the official documentation available at this [Link](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/troubleshooting.html), but I was not successful. What modification do I need to make so that the 'work' folder becomes available for the default user "jovyan"? If the directory can be made available through another method, that would also be appreciated!

yml File

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-db1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: FapCov2103
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:      
      - "H:\\docs\\www\\public\\SCC0244\\data:/home/jovyan/work"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  
  nobel:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-db2
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: Nobel
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres2
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres2
    volumes:
      - "H:\\docs\\www\\public\\SCC0244\\data:/home/jovyan/work"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  jupyter:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Usando o Dockerfile personalizado
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - "C:\\Users\\ivanp\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\scc0244:/home/jovyan/work"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    container_name: jupyter-datascience
    
networks:
  mynetwork:
```

Dockerfile

```
# Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.
ARG REGISTRY=quay.io
ARG OWNER=jupyter
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=$REGISTRY/$OWNER/base-notebook
FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

LABEL maintainer="Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"

# Fix: https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL4006
# Fix: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC3014
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

USER root

# Defina variáveis de ambiente no Dockerfile
ENV GRANT_SUDO="yes"

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

# Install all OS dependencies for fully functional Server
RUN apt-get update --yes && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    # Common useful utilities
    curl \
    git \
    nano-tiny \
    tzdata \
    unzip \
    vim-tiny \
    # git-over-ssh
    openssh-client \
    # less is needed to run help in R
    # see: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/1588
    less \
    # nbconvert dependencies
    # https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex
    texlive-xetex \
    texlive-fonts-recommended \
    texlive-plain-generic \
    # Enable clipboard on Linux host systems
    xclip && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt 

# Create alternative for nano -> nano-tiny
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/nano nano /bin/nano-tiny 10

# Switch back to jovyan to avoid accidental container runs as root
USER ${NB_UID}
```

I tried following some recommendations from the official documentation available at this [Link](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/troubleshooting.html)